# Actionscript 3 Sound ioError Problem

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

i am having trouble with sound. i am loading it dynamically, url comes from flashvars.
App is working actually but stil gives error, unhandled ioError. but i already handled it.

`
        var sound:Sound = new Sound()

```
try{
    sound.load(new URLRequest(req));
} catch(e:IOError){
    trace("catch ioerror");
}   
sound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(evt:IOErrorEvent):void { trace("error:",evt) } );    

sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void{
    channel = sound.play(0,int.MAX_VALUE);  
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to rule it out, try commenting out the line `channel = sound.play(0,int.MAX_VALUE);` perhaps it is this that is throwing the error and not the load, and you have no catch around this.

Comment: that line is for looping. is there need to try catch block, if it is loaded, event will fire. did you guys tried .

Answer (score 0):

Try a neater approach in terms of code, might just have issues with your layout and such:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(req);
sound.load(request);

sound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, _ioError);
sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _complete);

function _ioError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("File was not found");
    _removeListeners();
}

function _complete(e:Event):void
{
    channel = sound.play(0,int.MAX_VALUE);
    _removeListeners();
}

function _removeListeners():void
{
    sound.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, _ioError);
    sound.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _complete);
}
```

Comment: ok my code was working. i am sorry i did not copy paste here. i have initted 2 times, and that was giving me error. now i figure it out. thanks